# Lax-Wendroff method for nonlinear hyperbolic systems of conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

In page 127 of R.J. LeVeque's "Numerical Methods for conservation laws" (Birkhäuser, 1992),

> There are various ways that [the Lax-Wendroff method for constant-coefficient linear hyperbolic systems] can be extended to give a second order method for nonlinear conservation laws. If we let $A(u) = f'(u)$ be the Jacobian matrix, then a conservative form of Lax-Wendroff is
>   $$
> U_j^{n+1} = U_j^n - \frac{k}{2h}(f(U_{j+1}^n - f(U_{j-1}^n)) + \frac{k^2}{2h^2} \big[ A_{j+1/2} (f(U_{j+1}^n) - f(U_j^n)) \\
> - A_{j-1/2} (f(U_{j}^n) - f(U_{j-1}^n)) \big] \, ,
> \tag{12.25}
> $$
>   where $A_{j\pm1/2}$ is the Jacobian matrix evaluated at $\frac12 (U_j^n + U_{j\pm 1}^n)$.

I am trying to understand the paragraph above, which is pretty much the same as in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method). First of all, how was this derived and how is it in conservative form? Moreover, Why are we evaluating a jacobian at $\frac12 (U_j^n + U_{j \pm 1}^n )$? Isnt this the value of the solution $u= u(x)$ evaluated at some discrete point? Im confused by this notation. Can someone clarify this?

My question is related to an exercise of this book:

> EXERCISE 12.3. [The method] $(12.25)$ reduces to [the classical linear Lax-Wendroff method] in the constant coefficient linear case and is second order accurate on smooth solutions (to nonlinear problems) and conservative. Verify these statements for at least [$(12.25)$] and write it in conservation form, determining the numerical flux function.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2886452/418542) is closely related: only the computation of the Jacobian at the cell interface differs. For the first part, the conservative form is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222792/418542).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the Taylor expansion 
$$
u(x,t+k)=u(x,t)+u_t(x,t)k+\frac12u_{tt}(x,t)k^2+...
$$
Use the PDE to convert time into space derivatives, $u_t=-[f(u)]_x$, then
\begin{align}
u_{tt}&=-[f(u)]_{xt}=-[f'(u)u_t]_x\\
&=[f'(u)[f(u)]_x]_x\\
\end{align}
Now realize this derivative structure using symmetric divided differences and a half-step scheme. Let the index denote the offset in $x$ direction in units of $h$
$$
[f'(u)[f(u)]_x]_x=\frac{f'(u_{+1/2})[f(u_{+1/2})]_x-f'(u_{-1/2})[f(u_{-1/2})]_x}h
$$
The $x$ derivatives at the half-steps are again approximated using central divided differences with step size $h/2$, 
$$
[f'(u)[f(u)]_x]_x=\frac{f'(u_{+1/2})\frac{f(u_{+1})-f(u)}h-f'(u_{-1/2})\frac{f(u)-f(u_{-1})}h}h
$$
and finally the midpoint arguments of the derivative of $f$ by $u$ can be approximated by the mean of the neighboring integer grid values, $u_{\pm 1/2}=\frac12(u+u_{\pm 1})$.

If one inserts this in backwards, using the full-step central derivative for the degree-1 term, $[f(u)]_x=\frac{f(u_{+1})-f(u_{-1})}{2h}$ one gets back to the given formula of the method.

Comment: Could you check your equations please! I think it should be $\frac{f(u)-f(u_{-1})}h$ for $[f'(u)[f(u)]_x]_x$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @jan.sende : Thank you, that was correct, the index was not shifted after copying the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more comment, which you probably know. The problem of the Lax-Wendroff scheme is that it contains zero numerical viscosity and therefore it cannot filter out oscillation which the scheme produces due to its second order approximation. For the practical use I recommend the TVD or ENO schemes, which are more sofisticated.

Comment: Are you missing a factor in your original equation? $u_t=-f'(u)u_x$

Comment: What wikipedia writes could be shortened as $u_t=-[f(u)]_x$. What you wrote reads as $u_t=-\frac{df}{du}(u)$, which is not the same.

Comment: You are right, I have to adapt the derivation a bit.